# Functions which depend on position and time: Functional notation and derivations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, physics, vector-fields

In his [MIT OCW course](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter08/section03.html),  Professor Kleitman explores the derivative of temperature when it depends on position *and* time:

> $T(x, y, z, t)$ ... is a function of position $(x, y, z)$ and time $t$... What is the derivative with respect to time of the temperature experienced by a body [under trajectory] $r(t)$?
> $$\begin{align*}
> dT &= \frac {\partial T}{\partial x} dx + \frac {\partial T}{\partial y} dy + \frac {\partial T}{\partial z} dz + \frac {\partial T}{\partial t} dt \\
> &\quad ... \\
> \frac {dT} t &= \nabla T \cdot \frac {dr}{dt} + \frac {\partial T}{\partial t}
> \end{align*}$$
> *(edited)*

The issue I have with this is that $T$ means three different things:

- A function depending on time only: $\frac {dT} t$
- A function depending on position only: $\nabla T$
- A function depending on both: $\frac {\partial T}{\partial t}$

Is there a simpler way to write this? I tried to use functional notation to simplify both the notation and the derivation:

Let $$\begin{align}
r \in \mathbb R^3 &\text{ (position)}\\
t \in \mathbb R &\text{ (time)}\\
U(r, t): \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R &\text{ (temperature at an arbitrary position and time)} \\
R(t): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3 &\text{ (a trajectory)} \\
T_R(t): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R = U(R(t), t) &\text{ (temperature along trajectory }R\text{ at time } t \text{)}.
\end{align}$$

Then $$\begin{align}
DT_R(t) &= \underbrace{\underbrace{DU(R(t), t)}_{1 \times 4}  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}DR(t) \\ 1\end{bmatrix}}_{4 \times 1}}_{1 \times 1}\\
\end{align}$$

I'd like to conclude that $$\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{DT_R(t) = (DU(t))_{xyz} \cdot DR(t) + (DU(t))_t}$$
$$DT_R(t) = (DU(R(t),t))_{xyz} \cdot DR(t) + (DU(R(t),t))_t$$

but I'm not sure that's any clearer.  The problem is that, while functional notation simplifies many things, including concepts, it gets very cumbersome when you have to talk about a subset of dimensions.

(Besides arguably simplifying notation, I believe this approach makes the actual derivation much clearer.)

Is my derivation correct? Is there a clearer way to write it? Is there a clearer way to handle this? See also [How to write clear proofs involving curves and surfaces: The path of steepest descent along an ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753441/how-to-write-clear-proofs-involving-curves-and-surfaces-the-path-of-steepest-de) for a similar issue.

Comment: The derivation is mostly fine, except that $DU(t)$ makes no sense. What you want are the spatial/time derivatives of $U$ evaluated at the point $(R(t),t)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4004117/568204) and the sublinks for more. Anyway let me assure you that writing things out correctly is not a bad thing, and clarifying this notational issue now (earlier the better) will only save you from lots of confusion later on.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks.  Fixed now? But that notation is still very opaque.  The gradient/Leibnitz notation used at the quote at the top, while being inconsistent, still makes the intent clear.

Comment: in my experience, it seems easy, then sometime afterwards things start looking confusing (especially if you start learning thermodynamics/Lagrangian mechanics), until you clarify the foundational question, and then everything looks simple again, i.e if we plot an understanding vs time graph, it looks like a $U$ shape :) The point is that it’s fine to use the abuse of notation as long as you (and whoever you’re writing for) know about it.